# how to pull custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, field, meta

I have a custom field, "price" and I want to pull that custom field for each individual post.

I have the code:

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

But this is pulling the value of the first post and applying it to all the posts. Can someone help me understand this code and understand why it's applying the same field value to all my posts? How can I make it pull the individual value for each post?

Thank you all, I'm really new at this.

Comment: Goto WordPress website and study function documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this line at the start of script:

```
global $post;
```

thn try with your code:

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have already checked it.

```
<?php
  global $wp_query;
  $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
  echo get_post_meta($postid, 'yourcustomfield', true);
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: this worked but it has the odd side effect of duplicating my first post

Comment: Try to remove wp_reset_query(); and check.